# Why does this solution work? Leetcode #94

Tags: python, algorithm, recursion, tree, binary-tree

new to python, I am doing leetcode problem 94, Binary Tree Inorder Traversal. Given the root of a binary tree, return the inorder traversal of its nodes' values.

```
class Solution:
    def inorderTraversal(self, root: TreeNode) -> List[int]:
        if not root:return []
        res = []
        res+=self.inorderTraversal(root.left)
        res.append(root.val)
        res+=self.inorderTraversal(root.right)
        return res
```

I have seen this solution from the comments part of https://leetcode.com/problems/binary-tree-inorder-traversal/discuss/31381/Python-recursive-and-iterative-solutions

But I still don't get why it works. After `res.append(root.val)`, won't the res variable be re-assigned to [] during the recursion `res+=self.inorderTraversal(root.right)`? Or are res variables supposed to be different variables in different recursions?

Comment: `res` is defined on the local scope of the method... not globally. It won't be rewritten every recursion loop

Comment: @khelwood I have added the problem description.

Comment: so you need to lookup for recursions vs memory, how winding and unwinding recursions work with Stack or Heap, sorry it's a huge explanation to give in comments.

Comment: Yes to the final question: variables have local scope by default. Each execution context has its own `res` variable.

Answer (score 0):

Each recursive call allocates its own local `res` variable and returns it. The outermost (first) `res` is built by assembling (appending) results of inner/ (deeper) sub-problems.

However I would like to point out that the original program has mixed concerns of tree traversal and list creation. Here's an implementation of `inorder` that only focuses on traversal -

```py
def inorder(node):
  if not node: return
  yield from inorder(node.left)
  yield node.val
  yield from inorder(node.right)
```

To get a list from an iterable like `inorder`, we use the `list` constructor -

```
list(inorder(some_tree))
# => [ ... ]
```

Separation of concerns is fundamental technique used by successful programmers. It makes it easier to design/write functions and promotes code reuse. For this program it means you are not limiting only to creating lists; you could do anything while traversing the tree such as search, creating a new tree, printing to stdout, writing to a file, or making a network request.

```py
s = 0
for val in inorder(some_tree):
  print(f"node value: {val}")
  s += val
print(f"tree sum: {s}")
```

Wrapping everything in a `class` comes from languages like Java and C# but has no benefit in Python. Another indicator that the original program is not written by a fluent Python speaker is the use of CamelCase instead of snake_case -

```py
class solution:
  def inorder_traversal(self, root):
    return list(inorder(root))
```